# how we can instantiate from abstract class in dart?

Tags: dart, abstract

How we can instantiate from abstract class in dart like below:

```
int a = 5;
String a = ‘Hello’;
List<int> myList1= [50,60,70];
```

these classes are all abstract but we get instance from each one.

Comment: In addition to [julemand101's answer explaining `factory` constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69586828/), your example doesn't actually instantiate anything from the abstract base classes.  Your example uses  `int`, `String`, and `List<int>` *literals*.  There's nothing unusual about doing `SomeBaseClass base = someDerivedInstance;`.

Answer (score 3):

Abstract classes is allowed to have factory constructors and/or static methods which returns instances which are compatible with the abstract class.

So we can do things like this where the actual implementation is hidden from users of our library:

```
abstract class A {
  String getString();

  factory A() => _A();
  static A getA() => _A();
}

class _A implements A {
  @override
  String getString() => 'Hello World';
}

void main() {
  A a1 = A();
  A a2 = A.getA();
  print(a1.getString()); // Hello World
  print(a2.getString()); // Hello World
  print(a1.runtimeType); // _A
  print(a2.runtimeType); // _A
}
```

Comment: i understood about List class,but about String class ,it is a final abstract class and you can't implement or extend that,so how we write String a="test"

Comment: Dart have some core types like `int`, `double`, `num` and `String` which you are not allowed to extend or implement since Dart makes a lot of optimization assumptions based around the fact that no other type can exist of these. Also, these types is specified in the Dart language specification to have specific syntax for creating instances of these types (with the exception of `num` which is just a class used to represent a common type for `int` and `double`). So you cannot write your own Dart code and make a class that behave exactly like one of the Dart core types.

Comment: So how we get instance from String class(or int) while these are abstract and don't have subclass?

Comment: @a.rah By using e.g. `5` if we want a `int`, `5.0` if we want a `double` or `'Some String'` if we want a `String`.

Comment: The reason for this works is that these types is literals which is part of language itself. So when the compiler sees this syntax, it knows how to insert instances of these types into the compiled program. You can call it magic but nearly all programming languages have concept of special inbuilt types which behaves in a special way.

Answer (score 3):

The expressions `5`, `'hello'` and `[50, 60, 70]` are *literals*, not class instantiations (no constructor is invoked in the creation, well, as far as you know).
The literals produce values which satisfy the interfaces `int`, `String` and `List<int>`, in some magical way which the language doesn't specify (it just says what the end result must be), and the objects do not have to be actual instances of those types.

In practice, they aren't. Each platform has their own implementation. On the native VM, `5` is an instance of `_Smi` (short for "small integer"), `'hello'` is an instance of `_OneByteString` and `[50, 60, 70]` is an instance of `_GrowableList<String>`. All these implementations classes are hidden from users because they are platform-specific. On the web, each class uses an underlying JavaScript type, `Number`, `String` and `Array`, because those are very efficient, and then lies about it if asked, pretending that they are really Dart classes.

You *cannot* create an instance of an abstract class.
You *can* create an instance of a class which implements the interface of an abstract class. That's what's happening here — plus some platform-native magic to hide which class that is, because you shouldn't care about the native implementations below. (Also because that might just change in the next Dart SDK release, because some other implementation is more efficient.)