# A Dart List is abstract, but it can be instantiated. Why?

Tags: dart, abstract-class

The [Iterable Collection docs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables) state the following:

> In Dart, an `Iterable` is an abstract class, meaning that you can’t instantiate it directly. However, you can create a new `Iterable` by creating a new `List` or `Set`.

That makes sense to me. But then I realized, "Wait, `List` and `Set` are also abstract." List source code:

```dart
abstract class List<E> implements EfficientLengthIterable<E> {
```

How is it that the Dart analyzer knows I can't do this:

```dart
final myIterable = Iterable();
```

But I can do this:

```dart
Iterable<String> myIterable = List<String>.empty();
```

Is it because Dart follows the `exteral factory` to some concrete implementation somewhere? List source code:

```dart
external factory List.empty({bool growable = false});
```

I'm trying to understand abstract and concrete classes and how the Dart analyzer knows what error message to give me.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370049/why-is-map-and-list-instantiable-and-yet-they-are-abstract-classes-in-dart and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586709/how-we-can-instantiate-from-abstract-class-in-dart

Comment: @mmcdon20, Thank you, I'll mark this as a duplicate.